# No Space in Method Call Violation: Don't add a space between the method name and the parentheses. (no_space_in_method_call)

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftlint

I have many such warnings in the code:

> "No Space in Method Call Violation: Don't add a space between the method name and the parentheses. (no_space_in_method_call)"

although there are no spaces and square brackets there, what could be the problem?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhqGw.png)

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self?.StartActivityWithIgnore(activityIndicator: (self?.activityIndicator)!)
}
```

An attempt to create a similar function was unsuccessful.

Comment: Are you using SwiftLint or something similar? I don't think that is a built-in warning that the Swift compiler would emit.

Comment: Yes, it looks like something you have added to Xcode doesn't understand about trailing closure syntax

Comment: I use SwiftLint, but changing the minimum iOS version for pod files helped

Comment: Docs on the rule (https://realm.github.io/SwiftLint/no_space_in_method_call.html) say that "Minimum Swift compiler version: 5.0.0". So, I'd try to ensure that the Swift version of the project is set to at least 5, and also update SwiftLint (it might have bugs as well as everything else).